# Value NULL in PHP File after json_decode

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

The console.log produces mentioned below output a string and JSON string but the value received in PHP is an empty string and hence NULL after `json_decode()`, where is the problem?

I have mentioned the header also telling that the data will be of `JSON` form.

```
        function callAjax()
    {
    var data1 = $("#username").val();
    var data2 = $("#password").val();
    var dataToBePassed={User:data1, Pass:data2};
    console.log(dataToBePassed);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dataToBePassed));
    $.post( "yahaAaoJSONBeta.php", JSON.stringify(dataToBePassed), 
                    function(data) {
            $("#populate_this_bitch").html(data);
            }, "json");
                }
```

**The php file is:**

```
  <?php
header("Content-type: application/json");
$jsonObj  = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($jsonObj);
$readable = json_decode($jsonObj);
var_dump($readable);
echo $readable->{'User'};
 ?>
```